# Removing specific inputs in any text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm a complete newbie to programming and I wanna develop a one page-website that removes both numbers and this symbol ==> : from any given sentence.

Let's say you have the following:

(Hey Mr. 11, I'm 18, and I can't wait to turn 20, to own a :)

As you click generate you'd get the following results:

(Hey Mr., I'm, and I can't wait to turn, to own a)

How would you do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code so we can help you help yourself (read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why is this tagged R? There isn't any R code here

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dead simple implementation in HTML/JavaScript that uses a regex replacement, to get you started.

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('output').textContent =
    this.value.replace(/[0-9:]/g, '');
};
```

```html
Remove numbers (0-9) and colons (:) from input.
<br>Input: <input type="text" id="input" />
<br>Output: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: I clicked on "Run code snippet" and its working fine, but it's on StackOverflow, how can I add it to my own website, I'll add some CSS code to it to make it look better :)

Comment: @Jon your example implementation is excellent but can you perhaps provide the necessary accoutrement (<html>, <script> etc etc) so that Ayman can copy/paste the code into a blank text file and save it as file.html and it works (I tried this and it's not displaying the text as it does in the code snippet - I'm not sure why)

Comment: @user5783745 JavaScript has to go in a `<script>` tag. That's it.

Comment: @JonUleis I opened a new sublime text file, dropped in your code snippets exactly as they are and wrapped the first in `<script>` and `</script>`, saved it as test.html and opened it in chrome, but it doesn't display the text as I type it in like it does when you click on "Run code snippet" above. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @user5783745 Check your console for any errors. Could be cart before the horse - maybe you put the <script> tag above the HTML so it's looking for them before they're in the DOM.

Comment: @JonUleis it worked as soon as as the html block was placed before the javascript block. thanks for the help